# RabbitContainer create queue in new vhost

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, testcontainers

1. My problem: adding a listener configuration for a different virtual
   host,I try to test it with RabbitContainer. However, the problem is
   that `.withQueue()` method binds it under default vhost, not the one
   I set through `.withVhost()` method. Any suggestions how to declare
   it programmatically?
   I tried to inject RabbitAdmin and declare a queue programmatically,
   with no success: access was denied by rabbit-container.
   The solution of putting a test execution on debug and manually add queue under specific vhost through rabbit UI works(see pic).
2. Bonus question: is configuration of ConfigurationFactory injected to
   SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory enough to listen to specific
   queue with my @RabbitListener? I am afraid it requires some other
   beans  (i.e. RabbitAdmin?) which spring context configurate in
   separate config.

[image]

Comment: Use execInContainer and run the command you are familiar with instead of relying on withQueue or another utility methods.